# How to specify compiler optimizations in phoronix test suite?

Tags: benchmarking, compiler-optimization

I am trying to do some benchmarks on comparing the performance of different levels of compiler optimizations. Say gcc -o1, o2, o3. The benchmark tool I am using is Phoronix test suite. Does anybody know how to specify the compiler optimization levels? Preferably generate images like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the flags using the environment variables CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS?

e.g.

```
 export CFLAGS = "-O2"
```